# Binding for a GroupBox HeaderTemplate with MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datatemplate, groupbox

I want to create a GroupBox with a custom header, where besides the header title, i want to have an icon that is associated with a certain MVVM binding.

For example i got it working using this approach:

**View:**

```
<GroupBox>
    <GroupBox.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding BondHead2Enabled, Converter={StaticResource StateToIconConverter}}" />
            <Label Content="Bond Head 2"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox.Header>
    <finalBondView:BondheadTemplateView Content="{Binding BondHead2Content}"/>
</GroupBox>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public bool BondHead2Enabled => false;

public BondHeadTemplateViewModel BondHead2Content
{
    get { return _bondheadContents[1]; }
    set
    {
        if (_bondheadContents[1] != value && value != null)
        {
            _bondheadContents[1] = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("BondHead2Content");
        }
    }
}
```

However with this approach i have to repeat a lot of code on each groupbox i have. So i want to turn this into a Header Template where i can just associate a style instead of copy pasting the header. 
Therefore i created this style:

**Style**

```
<Style x:Key="StatusGroupBox" TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding EnabledStatus, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=GroupBox}, Converter={StaticResource StateToIconConverter}}" />
                    <Label Content="{Binding Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=GroupBox}}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**ViewModel**

```
<GroupBox Header="Bond Head 3" Margin="5" Style="{DynamicResource StatusGroupBox}">
    <finalBondView:BondheadTemplateView Content="{Binding BondHead3Content}"/>
</GroupBox>
```

I can get the content for the label using this style, but i can't get the boolean value that i need to know which icon to display, named *EnabledStatus* in the style. So how can i *pass* this information to te style in a generic way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading a bit more on the recommended topics I found a effective way to do this. Instead of binding just a String to the Header property, i binded a structure with both a Title (string) and a status (boolean). Then i read each field in the style. The code:

**Support class**

```
public class StatusHeaderTemplate
{
    public string HeaderTitle { get; set; }
    public bool HeaderStatus { get; set; }

    public StatusHeaderTemplate(string title, bool status)
    {
        HeaderTitle = title;
        HeaderStatus = status;
    }
}
```

**Style**

```
<Style x:Key="MountainTopStatusGroupBox" TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding HeaderStatus, Converter={StaticResource StateToIconConverter}}" />
                    <Label Content="{Binding HeaderTitle}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**View**

```
<GroupBox Margin="5" Header="{Binding BondHead1StatusHeader}" Style="{DynamicResource MountainTopStatusGroupBox}">
    <finalBondView:BondheadTemplateView Content="{Binding BondHead1Content}"/>
</GroupBox>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public StatusHeaderTemplate BondHead1StatusHeader => new StatusHeaderTemplate("Bond Head 1", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the Binding of that Boolean Value in the Style:

```
Source="{Binding DataContext.EnabledStatus, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=GroupBox}, Converter={StaticResource StateToIconConverter}}"
```

This is because the EnabledStatus is not a property of the Groupbox itself, but of it's DataContext.

Comment: I think i tried this solution too, but i was making some mistake with the path or the relativesource. But anyway this solution wouldn't fit my needs exactly because i am not binding a specific datacontext to each groupbox, they are just inheriting the one used in the View (parent). With this approach i could only read the EnabledStatus for one groupbox, not in a generic way.
But the solution i found is somewhat similar. In the beggining I was confused on how to pass the two parameters to the template, instead of just 1 (the header title).